# HTTP: an API documentation says I must "store a cookie", do I need to send it during next request?

Tags: http, cookies

I have little experience with web programming and I am implementing an interface where I sent a HTTPS POST Request (with user/password), receive a XML, then I send another HTTPS POST Request (with an additional "passcode" dependent on the XML), receive a XML, (then I am logged in) then I send a HTTPS GET request and get an XML (the data I actually want).

The documentation says: The following cookies are sent to the application ... and then it says: "the application must be able to store cookies".

I wondered why I should store cookies if I am never asked for it. I just started programming that protocol but I saw in a response that I was sent a cookie. Now I wondered whether I need to store the cookie (and worry about it) if I am never asked for it?

Comment: So the documentation of the API of the remote service says that a client *must* be able to accept cookies but you are able to retrieve the resource *without* cookies?

Comment: Yes I can get it without the cookie.

Comment: Or let's be more precise. I have not yet tried. Maybe they implied that I must sent the cookie (as Andrey suggested). So thanks for your answer, too. It seems to me that it is quite common to set-up a http interface like that to make it safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wondered why I should store cookies if I am never asked for it.

Asked by who? User? User should not care. Cookies are part of protocol that you must implement to be able to communicate with that server.

That protocol spec says that you should store cookies - where you like, and send with each request.

Comment: Asked by the service (server). It does not say to send it. Maybe I have to and they missed it in the spec. But as I said I am not experienced with web programming. So I wanted some advice.

Comment: @Jürgen Hollfelder how do you think service will tell you about that? it sends you cookies "I was sent a cookie", this usually implies that you sent them back. Plus it is stated explicitly in documentation, so you definitely should follow.

Comment: The documentation says "The application should be able to store cookies". It does not say "... and must send them with each request". But if this is normal and common then I would do so. So thanks for your help. I think I got my question answered.

Comment: @Jürgen Hollfelder ok, this document was intended to advanced web developers.  HTTP standard is here: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt , look at section 4.3.4 : "When it [client] sends a request to an origin server, the user agent sends a Cookie request header to the origin server if it has cookies that are applicable to the request". So standard is very clear: send cookies if you have them. Your document says store them. well, conclusion is: store and send back :)